# angularjs digest issue and lack of understanding

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, rest, digest-authentication

I am using angular for client side and codeigniter php for backend and for rest server. When I turn on basic auth on rest server I can reach to data from client side in this way:

```
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/myDomain',
            headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username:password")}
```

But when I turn on digest I can't just change Basic to Digest and reach to data. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS and Digest HTTP Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531753/angularjs-and-digest-http-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Basic and Digest are like different languages, you also can't say "how r u" to a Non-English-speaking person and expect a useful answer. In fact, Digest uses a Challenge Response protocol and Basic doesn't.

More clearly, your HTTP header value needs to be calculated from the username/password combo *plus* the previous server answer.

[image: sequence diagram visualizing the HTTP digest authentification]

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531753/angularjs-and-digest-http-authentication